# Program halts after successive timeout while performing GET request

Tags: http, go, get, timeout

I'm making a crawler that fetches html, css and js pages. The crawler is a typical one with 4 go-routines running concurrently to fetch the resources. To study, I've been using 3 test sites. The crawler works fine and shows program completion log while testing two of them.

In the 3rd website however, there are too many timeouts happening while fetching css links. This eventually causes my program to stop. It fetches the links but after 20+ successive timeouts, the program stops showing log. Basically it halts. I don't think it's problem with Event log console.

Do I need to handle timeouts separately ? I'm not posting the full code because it won't relate to conceptual answer that I'm seeking. However the code goes something like this :

```
for {
    site, more := <-sites
    if more {
        url, err := url.Parse(site)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        response, error := http.Get(url.String())

        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println("There was an error with Get request: ", error.Error())
            continue
        }

        // Crawl function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of the http client is to block forever. Set a timeout when you create the client: (http://godoc.org/net/http#Client)

```
func main() {
    client := http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 30,
    }
    res, err := client.Get("http://www.google.com")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

After 30 seconds `Get` will return an error.